# pruning text files with delimiters

Tags: bash, perl

Manually editing files is rather tedious in vim, I'd like to streamline it if I can :)

The question is, I'd like to have a script to remove the the selected item and if its got a delimiter to remove it also.

Its either separated with a "|" or a "," or not.

./remove-text test.com

```
 test.com|test3.org|filename.co.uk|files.qwe|loop.zya|....
 test3.org,filename.co.uk,test.com,files.qwe,loop.zya,...
 test3.org,filename.co.uk,test.com##[mode;]
 filename.co.uk,files.qwe,loop.zya##["test.com"]
 test.com##[mode2;]
```

Would become:

```
 test3.org|filename.co.uk|files.qwe|loop.zya|....
 test3.org,filename.co.uk,files.qwe,loop.zya,...
 test3.org,filename.co.uk##[mode;]
 filename.co.uk,files.qwe,loop.zya##["test.com"]
```

Note; Trying to avoid the need to make backup/temp file and edit the file directly.

Comment: Your example is puzzling: the 5th line is deleted --  why? I would have expected the 5th line to become `##[mode2;]`.

Comment: It would remove the line, if its only one there.

Comment: The handling of line 5 seems different than the handling of line 3. The `##[mode;]` was deleted in one case but retained in the other. What's the rule here? And does the rule apple specifically to markers that begin with `##` or does it apply to any text that is part of a cell where we are deleting an item from the cell?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
while(<DATA>)
{
    ($line .= $_)=~s/([\|\,\s]*)(?:test\.com|[a-z]+\-\[a-z]+)\b([\|\,\s]*)/$1$2/g;
}
print $line;

__DATA__
test.com|test3.org|filename.co.uk|files.qwe|loop.zya|....
test3.org,filename-co.uk,test.com,files.qwe,loop.zya,...
test3.org,filename.co.uk,test.com##[mode;]
filename.co.uk,files.qwe,loop-zya##["test.com"]
test.com##[mode2;]
```

Use `use strict` and `use warnings` definitely.